# C# ASP.NET MVC 4 - html.TextBoxFor value attribute empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two fields in my form which should be prefilled from the model. The fields are read-only. For the Email field, my form is correctly prefilled. But for my Username field, the value attribute remains empty. I can't seem to find out why the value of the Username field remains empty.

[image]
Both values get filled in the model.
[image]

```
        <div class="form-group input-group required-field-block">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            </span> 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Username", readOnly = "readonly" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input-group required-field-block">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
            </span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email", readOnly = "readonly" })
        </div>
```

Email is prefilled:
[image]
Username is not (notice the value attribute):
[image]

---

Result from fiddler:
[image]

---

Printing `@Model.UserName` on random places at my view, returns the correct value

```
        <div class="form-group input-group required-field-block">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            </span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Username", readOnly = "readonly" }) <!-- NO VALUE -->

            @Model.UserName <!-- Prints name perfectly -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Any chance you are updating the username in the view before you create the TextBox?

Comment: @Nava-Prev.Queti, I just checked there is only referenced twice to "Username"

Comment: This might seem silly, but can you view source and see what the server is actually returning. When using the Developer Tools, you are seeing the current state of the DOM, it's very possible that you could have something client-side that is overriding the value. So view source so you can see what is being sent from the server

Comment: In your watch window, Username is spelled with a lower case 'n' for name.  In your Textbox declaration, it has an upper case 'N'.  Try making it a lower case 'n' and see if that fixes your problem.

Nevermind, just looked at it again, and saw where that conversion was done.

Comment: So this should have absolutely no barring on it at all, but instead of creating a new object in your View method, what about creating an object above it, and then passing that object in.  At least that way you can see that the model is populated correctly instead of indirectly as you showed in the code above.  Again, I don't think it will have any bearing on the issue, but it simplifies the issue a bit more.

Comment: @Nava-Prev.Queti, not silly at all. I included a screenshot from Fiddler with the HTML response in my question. Murat, yeah added a comment to your response.

Comment: @Nate, trying that now but it should work. Because if I put a breakpoint in my view, the values are filled

Comment: Just double checking that your action method is called ForgotPasswordConfirmation, because you are requesting the "CreatePassword" view from your action and in the form you are posting "CreatePassword". So basically, are you looking at the correct view. #imRunningOutOfIdeas

Comment: @ Model.Username prints correct value?  Your TextBoxFor says it should be @ Model.UserName that would print the correct value.  Was that edit a typo?

Comment: Sound like the issue is with the TextBoxFor HtmlHelper. Any chance you have an Editor Template in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates?

Comment: This sounds like you either have the model as a parameter in your GET method, or your submitting the form to a POST method and updating the value of `UserName` and returning the view. If so, the `TextBoxFor()` will only ever display the original value (when the model is bound), because the HtmlHelper methods use the values from `ModelState`

Comment: @Nava-Prev.Queti, I don't have any Editortemplates. But I renamed the field from UserName to User in the model and it resolved the issue. Can you post your answer as a solution.

Comment: @Reinard. Changing the name from `UserName` to `User` could not possibly solve this unless you have other major problems with your code. You should show your controller methods.

Comment: @MuratYıldız, Your answer has got nothing to do with the issue. If `@Model.UserName` displays correctly but `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)` does not, its because the value for `UserName` in `ModelState` is `null`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sound like the issue is with the TextBoxFor HtmlHelper. Any chance you have an Editor Template in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates?

Comment: I did not have any EditorTemplates. But I renamed the Property from 'Username' to 'User' and the problem was resolved.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to to with the issue!